# Still receiving (413) Request Entity Too Large from WCF

Tags: wcf

I have looked at most of the questions that relate to this issue and none of the solutions are working. The binds that I have are listed below...

**Server**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UploadSoap" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="Transport"></security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UploadSoapWeb" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
</webHttpBinding>
<client>
    <endpoint address="https:.../upload.asmx" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UploadSoapWeb" contract="Upload.UploadSoap" name="UploadSoap" />
</client>
```

**Client**

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_service" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://.../service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_service"
            contract="HH.service" name="BasicHttpBinding_service" />
    </client>
```

I have tried both the basic binding and the web binding but I'm still receiving the error message.

Thanks

Comment: Are you hosting your service in IIS or is it self hosted? If IIS what version off IIS?

Comment: Could you update server bindings in the question to show the configuration for the service endpoint as well.

Comment: The only endpoint statements are listed above that is included in the client. There is no <services> or <service> statement in web.config.

Comment: You have a client -> server1 -> server2 call flow, which server is returning the 413?

Comment: No server2. It's client to server and the result code coming back from the server is a 413

Comment: What is the relevance of the client endpoint in your server configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set an explicit binding for your service so it will default to `basicHttpBinding` with default configuration values. The default value for `maxReceivedMessageSize` will be 64KB.

Keep in mind that `maxReceivedMessageSize` is only applicable for the message receiver and not the message sender. The client does not need to set these values if it is sending a large message.

Update your server side binding to the following:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <!-- Unnamed (default) binding-->
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text" /> <!-- Consider using Mtom if you're transfering binary data-->
    <binding name="UploadSoap">
        <security mode="Transport"></security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<client>
    <endpoint address="https:.../upload.asmx" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="UploadSoap"
              contract="Upload.UploadSoap" name="UploadSoap" />
</client>
```

The unnamed binding will provide the default values for any endpoint, server or client, using the `basicHttpBinding` without a `bindingConfiguration`.

I've assumed that your clients are not receiving a large message in response.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'm not sure why. The original statement had bindingConfiguration="UploadSoap" and there was a binding called that above it but it did include the security statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving the 413 error from the service, then the problem appears to be that your service config does not have any explicitly defined **service** endpoints, so the binding configuration that you've created isn't being used.

You need to add a `<services>` section to your **service** config, like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="YourServiceName">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="UploadSoap"
              contract="YourContractName" />
  </service>
</services>
```

As currently posted, there is nothing that tells WCF to use your defined binding configuration for the service, so by default out of the box WCF will use `basicHttpBinding` with the default (lower) values.

A second way to resolve this issue is to define a binding configuration and set it as the default for that type of binding by omitting the `name` attribute, like this:

```
<binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <security mode="Transport"></security>
</binding>
```

I generally prefer the first method (setting an explicit service endpoint), but either should work.

Comment: If I remove the name from the basicHttpBinding and also remove bindingConfiguration from the endpoint I receive an error stating it cannot find the endpoint.